# Kotlin : When and How Should One Use Lambda Expressions

Tags: android, lambda, kotlin

I have been moving on to Kotlin for my Android Projects lately and have a problem understanding the Lambdas. When we convert a Java file to a Kotlin file we see many lambda expressions.

When and how should one exactly use a lambda function? Also, what is the difference between a higher order function and a lambda function/expression?

Answers specifically in context to Android would be helpful.

Comment: They're a convenience to save you unnecessary typing. Instead of having to write something like `someView.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener {
            override fun onClick(v: View?) {
                Log.v("Foo", "onclick")
            }
        })` you can simply say `someView.setOnClickListener { Log.v("Foo", "onclick") }` if all you care about is the `onClick` event.

Comment: Under the hood, an anonymous `OnClickListener` object is still being created, it's just that _you_ don't have to explicitly type all that out when the compiler can do it for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> When and how should one exactly use a lambda function? Also, what is
>   the difference between a higher order function and a lambda
>   function/expression?

A **lambda** is an anonymous function. It allows you to write functions without naming them.

A **higher-order** function is a function that takes another function as an argument (often passed as a **lambda**) *or* returns one as a result.

It’s difficult to tell you when a lambda actually *should* be used. As already seen, higher-order functions are probably the main use case. It’s a great way to pass „what should be done“ into another function. Many standard functions do use this. One simple example is `forEach` on a collection:

```
listOf(1,2,3).forEach{
   //tell what to do with each element in this lambda
}
```

Also a good place to find lambdas is [DSLs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/type-safe-builders.html) like the [Anko](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko) library includes one. These constructs  also make heavy use of lambdas.

Comment: This sometimes is possible but you can’t tell in most cases

Comment: So at the end of it, they just save our time and avoid from writing unnecessary code, as also mentioned by Michael.

Answer (score 6):

For **Lambda**

- Lambda is a literal function which means it is not declared but
  passed as an expression.
- Lambda expression is always surrounded by
  curly braces {...}
- Parameters types are optional if they can be
  inferred.
- Lambda’s body goes after the arrow ->.
- Similar to regular
  function, lambda has a function type.

```
{a:Int, b:Int -> a + b} // lambda of function type: (Int, Int) -> Int

// Equivalent function 
fun sum(a:Int , b:Int) = a + b
```

--)We can assign lambda to a variable of similar function type:

```
var sum: (Int, Int) -> Int = {a:Int, b:Int -> a + b}
```

--)Which can be written without parameters types.

```
val sum: (Int, Int) -> Int = {a , b -> a + b} 

 println(sum(2,3)) // call sum
```

### Special Case: Lambda with single parameter

Lambda with single parameter is a special case.

The single parameter can be omitted along with the arrow `->` and use it as a reference to the single parameter.

Regular way:
`var increment: (Int) -> Int = { a -> a + 1 }`

Special case, single parameter is referenced as it
`var increment: (Int) -> Int = { it + 1 }`

### return in lambda?

```
 val sum: (Int, Int) -> Int = {a , b -> 
    println("a = $a")
    println("b = $b")
    a + b // last expression is returned
}
```

*from example,By default, the last expression of a lambda is implicitly returned.*

### Anonymous Functions

Anonymous function is also a literal function which means it is not declared but passed as an expression.
Anonymous function is a regular function without a name.
Similar to regular functions, anonymous functions have function type.

```
var sum: (Int, Int) -> Int = fun(x: Int, y: Int): Int = x + y

 println(sum(2,3)) // call sum
```

### Higher-Order Functions

--)Higher-order functions can take functions as parameters or return a function.

--)The type of the parameter accepting the function or the return type is declared using function type.

```
//  Higher-Order Function
 fun higherOrderSum(a:Int, b:Int, f: (Int, Int) -> Int): Int{
return f(a,b)
  }
  typealias someType = (Int, Int) -> Int

  fun main() {  
  val lambdaSum: someType = {a , b -> a + b}     
  println(higherOrderSum(2, 3, lambdaSum)) // 5
   }
```

### Lambda in android

```
val view = findViewById(R.id.welcomeMessage)
view.setOnClickListener { v -> navigateWithView(v) }
```

As you can see, the left side defines the input values of the function (in this case a view), and the right side declares the operation that function will perform.

### How to define a function that accepts lambdas

```
fun setOnClickListener(listener: (view: View) -> Unit){}
```

This is known as a Higher-Order Function, because it is a function that receives a function by parameter, or that returns a function.