# Why does this Kotlin function definition have an extra empty set of parentheses before the return type?

Tags: function, kotlin, parameters, return-type

I'm going through one of Google's Kotlin codelabs. I'm in Kotlin fundamentals under Android basics with Compose > Building app UI > Kotlin fundamentals, and I'm on section 5, "Use function types and lambda expressions in Kotlin".

I get to section 4 of codelab 5, "Use functions as a data type". Step 3 has you define a function trickOrTreat() with this line:

`fun trickOrTreat(isTrick: Boolean): () -> Unit {`

But what the crap is that second empty set of parentheses for?

I get every other part of this. "fun" is the keyword for a function, "trickOrTreat" is the name. Then the first set of parentheses is this function's parameters, which there's one, "isTrick", which is type Boolean. Then, the colon signals you're about to specify the function's return type.. but WHAT is the set of blank parentheses before that for. Is it some second parameter thing? How come in every other function definition I've seen where you specify return type, they aren't there, just -> Type, then the opening curly brace denoting the start of the function's body code?

I can't figure out what they're there for, and they never say, certainly not in that lesson, the first place they've used them like that. I've even googled it, going as general as 'kotlin "() ->"', and I can't figure out what this is.

And, I know it has to be there! I first noticed this when I didn't type them into my lesson code in Kotlin Playground, because far as I know you're not supposed to, this function already has parameters defined. And my code *didn't work*. After very careful rereading of the lesson, I finally found them; but if I'm going to use them myself, I need to understand why they're there?

All I know is it works if they're there, it doesn't compile if they're not, and neither Google nor kotlinlang.org will tell me why. Why are they there, what are they for, why does compilation work if they're present and break if they're not? How do I make them make sense in my mental model of Kotlin function definitions?

Comment: Earlier in that codelab, there was `val treat: () -> Unit = { println("Have a treat!") }`. Do you understand the meaning of `()` in that code? It's the same thing here.

Comment: Read this page of the Kotlin documentation https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#higher-order-functions

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kotlin : When and How Should One Use Lambda Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47110879/kotlin-when-and-how-should-one-use-lambda-expressions)

Comment: @Sweeper Ah yep, when it was there I saw it as meaning the function we're putting into "treat" has no parameters, and really it has no return either since that's just "-> Unit". It just looked weird to me since it was the return of trickOrTreat() instead of being the first bit of a function declaration like that.

Answer (score 0):

The return type of the function is `() -> Unit`. The arrow signifies that it's a function. The parentheses before the arrow means that function takes no arguments and `Unit` after the arrow means the function returns `Unit`.

To be clear, `trickOrTreat` is a function that itself returns a function, with the return type as I've described above.

Comment: So that whole construct,
'() -> Unit'
is a stand-in for the function that trickOrTreat() is going to return? And that function won't have any parameters because those parentheses are empty, and Unit is this inner function's return type? But really the whole inner function is the thing that trickOrTreat() is returning, yeah?

So also, if that inner function being returned by trickOrTreat() had parameters there'd be something in that set of parentheses, wouldn't there.

Comment: `trickOrTreat` returns "a function that takes no arguments and returns `Unit` (aka it doesn't return anything)". In section 4 it shows what the implementation is, but basically it returns a function that prints a constant string – so a function that takes no arguments and returns nothing, since `println(...)` returns `Unit`